# Reset Taskbar Flash in C#

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop, user32

I have an application where the taskbar flashes if an event has occurred. This is working perfectly, and was relatively easy to implement using a Win32 API described below:
http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2008/04/19/3392.aspx

However, when I stop the flashing, **sometimes the application is stuck in the "highlighted" state in the taskbar**. This only gets reset by clicking on the application in the taskbar, minimizing it, then re-maximizing it. Is there a way to clear this from being highlighted without any user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of flashing it you could put an overlay icon on it - one line of code from C# with the Code Pack. Then when you want to clear it you could take the overlay icon away - again one line of code. Windows 7 only, however.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code that you are using to "Stop" the flashing?

Have you also considered using a different flag such as:

// flash until the window comes to the foreground 
FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 12;

You will still need to click on the applicaiton to get the flash to stop, but you should not have to minimize then re-maximize the app to get the flash to stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the [FlashTaskbar](https://github.com/melenaos/snippets/blob/master/FlashTaskbar) snippet and use the following code

`FlashWindow(Form.Handle, FlashMode.FLASHW_STOP)`